# Slack API MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp T-SQL Cannot send message through

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to send message to a slack channel from a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @obj INT
DECLARE @url varchar (200)
DECLARE @resp varchar (200)
DECLARE @str as varchar(200)
DECLARE @token as varchar(200)
    
SET @str = 'channel=U015WQQ75RB&text=TestTestTest'
SET @url = 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage'
SET @token = 'Bearer xoxb-MY-TOKEN-HERE'

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj,'open',NULL,'POST',@url, false
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj,'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization' ,@token
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj,'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send', NULL, @str
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'ok', @resp out

print @resp

EXEC sp_OADestroy @obj
```

Can someone guide me what I'm doing wrong here? I've been struggling with this for 3 days.

I've tried debugging with requestbin and all the parameters and headers are being sent from SQL Server to webservice.
But when I use the Slack API, I'm getting no response from Slack API. No error. Nothing.

If I call this URL from browser the message gets sent.
https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?token=xoxb-my-token&channel=U015WQQ75RB&text=TestTestTest

In my opinion im unable to send the parameters in correct format.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It might help to mention what exactly is going wrong. Are you receiving errors from the API itself in your response? Is nothing being sent? Is SQL Server throwing errors? With the question in its current state you're most likely not going to receive help. Also small sidenote, SQL Server 2008 has reached end of lifetime and is officially no longer supported.

Comment: Stop using the old, error-prone, and impossible-to-debug ole automation procedure. Implement your interface using a clr procedure.

Comment: I've added some more details to the question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Why are you setting the token in a request header? In the URL you used as an example, it is part of the query string. So why not send it as part of the POST data, i.e., in `@str`?